# Import HTML via Command Line per documentation

Tags: command-line, evernote

Per [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enscript.php) in Evernote's Developer Documentation, I should be able to create a note from an existing html page with the command line syntax : Evernote myfile.html.

It works fine for myfile.txt but simply ignores an .html file.

This [previous forum post](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/78507-windows-command-line-evernoteexe-to-create-note-not-working/) from 2014 seems to suggest this a long standing known issue that has not been corrected,nor has the documentation changed to indicate this is not the desired/expected behavior.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a simple way to import a HTML file into Evernote not as an attachment, but the note itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question.  I  too would like to know the answer.

Comment: I just tried this using an HTML file that I saved off from a web page and it worked fine - it created a new note with the note content being the web page as expected. When you say "simply ignores", can you be more specific - i.e. does it not create a new note at all, does it create a new note with no content, etc?

Comment: I had tested this with several HTML files and it would look like it was processing and then nothing appeared in Evernote. And no error message on the command line.

After reading here today, I went in and gave it another shot using the 'ReleaseNotes.html' file in the same folder as Evernote.exe.  It worked.  

So then I tried it on an HTML file generated by Google Takeouts of a Google Keep record.  It put it into a note as an attachment, yet the file comes up properly in a browser.

So it appears to work, but something in some files keep it from working as expected.